# Usar função no datatables

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

Tenho esta função de forma ao colocar o preço, automaticamente substitui os zeros pelos valores colocados e mantem o ponto fixo:

```
$(function() {
  $('.Preco2').maskMoney({ decimal: '.', thousands: ' ', precision: 2 });
})
```

No `html` faço-o desta forma:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control Preco2" name="Preco2[]" value="0.00">
```

Mas uso a função `datatables` onde mostra 5 linhas por página:

```
(function ($) {$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#employee_ta22').DataTable();
    responsive: true
} );
$('#employee_ta22').dataTable({                           
 "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "iDisplayLength": 5,
        "oLanguage": {
    "sProcessing": "Aguarde enquanto os dados são carregados ...",
    "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registos por página",
    "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registo correspondente ao criterio encontrado",
    "sInfoEmtpy": "Exibindo 0 a 0 de 0 registos",
    "sInfo": "Exibindo de _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ registos",
    "sInfoFiltered": "",
    "sSearch": "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span>",
    "oPaginate": {
       "sFirst":    "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-fast-backward'></span>",
       "sPrevious": "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-backward'></span>",
       "sNext":     "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-forward'></span>",
       "sLast":     "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-fast-forward'></span>"
     }
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

O problema é que a `class preco2` só funciona na primeira página (nas primeiras 5 linhas) quando retorna a tabela, na segunda página e nas outras deixa de funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua função procura por todos os elementos `.Preco2` e aplica a mascara nesses elementos.

Obviamente essa mascara só é aplicada em elementos existentes no seu documento, se eventualmente um novo `.Preco2` for renderizado na página, você terá que aplicar a mascara novamente.

O `DataTables` te oferece alguns eventos para tratar isso, você pode criar um handler no evento [draw](https://datatables.net/reference/event/draw), que é invocado quando o `DataTables` renderiza a página, e então aplicar a mascara novamente para esses novos elementos que foram renderizados.

Exemplo:

```
$('#employee_ta22').DataTable().on('draw', () => {
    $('.Preco2').maskMoney({
        decimal: '.',
        thousands: ' ',
        precision: 2
    });
});
```